# Issue creating directory

Tags: java, minecraft

So I'm trying to launch a game and I'm having this error thrown at me:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create directory C:\Users\ashley\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-openal\3.3.1:natives-windows

I have tried creating this directory myself, but there is a colon in the name, which seems impossible, does anyone know what is going on here?

At the very end there's a colon in the "3.3.1:natives-windows" part

I would report the bug to the game manufacturer but it's on an unsupported legacy version so they won't help.
Any thoughts or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where did you got the path/directory from ? `natives-windows` sounds like the Maven classifier for Windows (Maven is a build and dependency-managment tool for Java and JAR-archives).

Comment: Did you try creating the directory without the colon and following parts?

Comment: I got the directory from the game launcher itself, I have not tried without colon, I'll do that and let you know

Comment: leaving the colon out just gives me the same error

Comment: leave out the `:natives-windows`, not just the colon. Having said that: some googling suggests that this is a problem  for pirated versions of Minecraft, so the most obvious solution is probably to just shell out the $25 or so and just buy it. But if this is a legal copy, then post a bug report on the minecraft bug tracker anyway, because even if they won't help you, at least now you have a link to include in your post that shows you first tried the official ways to get help.

Comment: I do have the legal version of the game haha, it's an old launcher tho :) I'm making an official bug report as we speak yeah. I have tried your method and leave out :natives-windows but that directory already exists so it doesn't make sense

Comment: Why are you using an old launcher? Doesn't the latest launcher still work on old versions of the game?

Comment: The latest launcher requires you to migrate your account, which is not possible for me. They refuse to help me with it too so yeah I'm stuck on the old one